# Less file watcher in PhpStorm produces: lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: less, phpstorm

I am trying to set up an file watcher for `.less` files, but it isn't working.

I have globally installed less via npm (`npm install -g less`). And after this I set up the file watcher according to this documentation from [JetBrains supprt](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d325751e160). Here is a picture of the settings:

[image: File Watcher]

Everytime I will change my `.less` files, it will produce the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc --no-color styles.less
lessc: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/styles.less'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What went wrong? Any suggestions?

Using the less compiler directly in the project folder via the command line works perfectly (e.g. `$ lessc styles.less styles.css`)

Comment: 1) *"Using the less compiler directly in the project folder via the command  -- line works perfectly"* Well, then try doing the same -- try `$FileDir$` in `Working Directory`. 2) I'm, for example, also using output file name as parameter: `--no-color $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` with `Cretate output file from stdout` option disabled.

Comment: On another hand: your error says "no such file or directory" -- does that path actually correct? What path `which lessc` (or maybe `where` -- sorry, not a Mac user here)? Will it work if you launch PhpStorm from terminal: e.g. `open -a /Applications/WebStorm.app/` ?

Comment: "try `$FileDir$` in `Working Directory`" solved the problem. Thank you! Because of this advice in the phpstorm manual: If the field is left blank, PhpStorm uses the directory of the file where the File Watcher is invoked, I thought, it would be automatically `$FileDir$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the less compiler directly in the project folder via the command -- line works perfectly (e.g. `$ lessc styles.less styles.css`)

Try doing the same then -- please try with `$FileDir$` in the "Working Directory" field.